# MongoDB org.bson.Document to POJO

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I use mongo driver 3.6.2 the return list is empty when i try to convert the return as List of POJO:

```
CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(mongoClientProvider.getMongoClient().getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));

MongoDatabase database = mongoClientProvider.getMongoClient().getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
MongoCollection<POJO> collection = database.getCollection(Constants.COLLECTION_NAME, POJO.class);  

List<POJO> results = collection.find().into(new ArrayList<POJO>());
```

Mongo driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? Is anything in it?

Comment: Yes it's the correct database and i have results if i remove POJO and replace it with Document